# upload large .xlsx file in gui java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

i have a large excel file containing 600.000 rows , i used XSSFWorkbook to upload the excel file at a Jtable in my GUI but it takes about 15 minutes to be done in eclipse and once i export my project to a jar file i can't do it even in the 15 minutes . Any help please ?
Here is the method , that i found in internet to upload my excel file .

```
void fillData(File file) {
    int index = -1;
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    try {
        try {
            String f = file.getPath();
            File file1 = new File(f);
            OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file1);
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProjectApp3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        String[] strs = new String[workbook.getNumberOfSheets()];
        //get all sheet names from selected workbook
        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
            strs[i] = workbook.getSheetName(i);
        }
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Input Dialog");
        //select sheet
        String selectedsheet = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                frame, "Which worksheet you want to import ?", "Select Worksheet",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, strs, strs[0]);

        if (selectedsheet != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
                if (workbook.getSheetName(i).equalsIgnoreCase(selectedsheet))
                    index = i;
            }
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
            //import headers data
            headers.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
                XSSFCell cell1 = row.getCell(i);
                headers.add(cell1.toString());
            }
            //import data
            data1.clear();
            for (int j = 1; j < sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1; j++) {
                Vector d = new Vector();
                row = sheet.getRow(j);
                int noofrows = row.getLastCellNum();
                for (int i = 0; i < noofrows; i++) {    //To handle empty excel cells 
                    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i,
                            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    d.add(cell.toString());
                }
                d.add("\n");
                data1.add(d);

            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic problem is that you're trying to give. your Jtable all the data at startup. This is going to be deeply problematic. You may want to write a custom subclass from AbstractTableModel. See the docs for Jtable that includes this:

```
  TableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
      public int getColumnCount() { return 10; }
      public int getRowCount() { return 10;}
      public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { return new Integer(row*col); }
  };
  JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
  JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

You can implement those three methods based on the info that POI gives you. But do lazy loading of the data, most especially for getValueAt(). Keep the spreadsheet file open and grab the data only when the user scrolls to view it.

Comment: And how i can do that lazy loading of the data please ?

Comment: Implement getValueAt(int row, int col) by stealing code from your original code. Something like row = sheet.getRowAt(row) (this might be an off-by-one error. might be row+1 or row-1). Similarly to get the column, then return the data at the cell in question.